# SVN $RECYCLE.BIN

Tags: windows, svn, visualsvn, visualsvn-server

Just installed VisualSVN server, what is "$RECYCLE.BIN" and can I hide / remove it?

Comment: In what context are you seeing this?

Comment: You've set its repository root to be the root of a drive? That's the Windows (hidden + system) recycle bin folder that it creates on every drive. Don't know why VisualSVN is showing it though, or how to configure it to ignore it.

Comment: That is the directory containing the recycle bin contents on Windows operating systems. Why are you asking in relation to VisualSVN server?

Comment: the repositories had their own drive which dont have windows installations. never mind this all got changed around anyway so this is no longer a problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appeared because the repository was put on the root of a separate drive, which even though it had no windows installation may have had or been marked for windows at one point.